# C++ Enforce function in derived class that accepts an object of the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want that all classes that are derived from my base class have this function:

```
class Derived : public Base{
public:
    void doSth(const Derived& d){
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this possible to enforce this in my base class?

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void doSth(const Base& b) = 0;  // ?
}
```

Comment: Nope. A base class cannot force a derived class to implement any method that's not a pure one. And even a pure method is not required to be implemented, unless an instance of the derived class actually gets instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, virtual function doesn't help since you change its signature.
Here's a possible implementation relying on C++11 features. It correctly detects the function with required signature.

```
#include <type_traits>


template<typename, typename T>
struct has_doSth {
    static_assert(
        std::integral_constant<T, false>::value,
        "Second template parameter needs to be of function type.");
};

// specialization that does the checking

template<typename C, typename Arg>
struct has_doSth<C, void(Arg)> {
private:
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr auto check(T*)
    -> typename
        std::is_same<
            decltype( std::declval<T>().doSth( std::declval<Arg>()) ),
            void
        >::type;  // attempt to call it and see if the return type is correct

    template<typename>
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);

    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;

public:
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};

template<typename T>
class Base {
 public:
  Base() {
    static_assert(has_doSth<T, void(const T&)>::value, "Missing required function in the derived class.");
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
class WellDerived : public Base<WellDerived> {
public:
  void doSth(const WellDerived& d){
      ...
  }
};

class BadDerived : public Base<BadDerived> {
public:
  void doSth(int d){
      ...
  }
};
```

Comment: That's great! Exactly what I was looking for.